# Getting TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

class LoginPage():

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def get_username_textbox(self):
        try:
            return self.driver.find_element_by_id('email')
        except:
            return None

    def get_password_textbox(self):
        try:
            return self.driver.find_element_by_id('pass')
        except:
            return None

    def get_login_button(self):
        try:
            return self.driver.find_element_by_id("loginbutton")
        except:
            return None

      def wait_for_login_page(self):
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30)
        element = self.driver.title("Facebook – log in or sign up")
        wait.until(EC.title_is(element))
```

Comment: Please five use entire Traceback or error string

Comment: self = <lib.ui.login_page.LoginPage object at 0x04654FF0>

    def wait_for_login_page(self):
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30)
\x1b[1m>       element = self.driver.title("Facebook \u2013 log in or sign up")\x1b[0m
E       TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

lib\ui\login_page.py:35: TypeError

Comment: ^ If you have more detail to offer Santosh, please edit it into the question, rather than adding it to the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

driver.title returns a string
I believe what you're trying to do is more inline with:

```
assert self.driver.title == "Facebook – log in or sign up"
```

Comment: Perfect.. thanks a lot for the solution. it works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

The title_is method of EC will take only text/string argument.

you can change it as follows.

```
def wait_for_login_page(self):
    wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30)
    wait.until(EC.title_is("Facebook – log in or sign up"))
```

Comment: This works perfectly to my code. Thank you :)